# how to get the first option value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using ajax on success im getting this result.so what i need is i need to get the first value `22` how can i do that in jquery ?

```
<option value=22>Bed</option>
<option value=23>Bath</option>
<option value=24>Kitchen</option>
<option value=25>Living</option>
<option value=26>Foam</option>
```

What i have tried is

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "{{ URL::to('getcategoryname') }}",
    data : {'GroupID':GroupID},
    success : function(data){       
        console.log(data.split('option').val()); //my tried line

       }
    });
```

Comment: `$('option:first').val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Assuming you are getting the partial data in string format.*

You can create a valid HTML then use various traversal method.

```
//Create select
var select = $j('<select />', { 
                 html : data
             });             

//find first child option then fetch its value
var v = select.children('option:first').val(); //Even select.children('option').val(); will work

console.log(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get first value from the following way.

```
var result = $('#selectId option[value!=""]').first().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to make a jQuery object wrapper and you don't need to use split here:

```
console.log($j(data).find('option:first').val()); //my tried line
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will get you the val of the selectedIndex

```
 $("#selectId ").prop("selectedIndex", 0).val();
```